# Ruby File IO question; Maintain file read position between script executions

Tags: ruby, text, file-io, parsing

I have two files `a.txt` and `b.txt` (henceforth `a` and `b`).

My script iterates through `a`, does some operation, and **potentially** inserts a line to `b`.

In the event the script stops, I need it to pick up where it left off. In the example below:

1. foo was copied to `b`
2. bar was copied to `b`
3. zim was **not** copied to `b` (did not pass some criteria)
4. gaz was copied to `b`
5. Script stops (for whatever reason)

When script starts again, how to open `a` and start on line `"dib"`?

### a.txt

```
foo
bar
zim
gaz      // <= last successful copy
dib      // <= I want to start here on next script execution
gir
```

### b.txt

```
foo
bar
gaz      // <= note omission of "zim" above gaz
```

---

### Note:

`a.txt` is almost 1,000,000 lines

Comment: you could create a third file `a.txt.ln` and store the line number to persist across executions of a.txt.  Then, when the script finishes normally, delete `a.txt.ln`

Comment: Jim, then how to open `a.txt` starting on a specific line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Macek - you could use seek to find the line in the original file.  Check out IO#seek http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002280